# Implementing ClearPath (crowd pathfinding)

Tags: mathematics, path-finding, steering-behaviors

This is the academic article:

http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/CA/ClearPath.pdf

Here is the confusing part (marked in red):

[image]

The first part is the path in which the object will move.

[image]

The first part of the formula in the red frame defines the sets of all possible velocities for agent A that will result in collision with obstacle B in the future (a cone).

[image]

I don't understand why they XOR the subtraction of A from that formula? I don't understand what it means to do exclusive or a substructed set?I want to understand it better.

Comment: It's not uncommon to define operator symbols to mean something domain specific. In your text, the `(+)` operator means "minkowski sum" and negation means "reflect object in reference point".

Comment: I see they stated that explanation. I did not read thoroughly enough. :|

Comment: At least I understand it perfectly now.

Comment: Post the answer if you have it now ;)